# Having a VB.net desktop application using DirectShow run on Windows 8 tablet

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, camera, directshow, tablet

I'm am working on a project where the user can take a picture on a tablet using the integrated cameras. So far the project can run on a Windows 7 tablet, but when trying to use it on a Windows 8 tablet, I cannot seem to get the capture to work. I am using DirectShow to bring in the feed and then pull the image out from the picturebox. For some reason in Windows 8, when I try pulling out the image, it gets saved as a black screen. I am trying to limit third party applications which is why I am avoiding using the tablets built in camera app.

What I'm wondering is if anyone has had an issue using DirectShow within Window 8 and if so, what are some possible areas I should check? If anyone has any suggestions/solutions I could try out, that would be helpful too. I've tweaked with DirectShow a lot already, but this is my first time using it so I am unsure of it's compatibility with Windows 8.